# I am trying to make a list by what I click on, but I can't [angularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to ask how to make a list of what I have clicked in a list... the example code is like below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <title>Belajar Angular</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('tesapp', []);
      app.controller('tesCtrl', function($scope,$http){
        $scope.DapatkanItem = function(){
          $http.get('/someurl').success(function(data){
            $scope.item = data;
          });
        };

        $scope.DapatkanItem();
        $scope.namaItem = [];
        $scope.klikIseng = function(item){
          $scope.namaItem.push(item.name);
        };

        $scope.tampilKlikItem = function(){

        }
      });

        app.filter('regex', function() {
          return function(input, field, regex) {
              var patt = new RegExp(regex);
              var out = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
                  if(patt.test(input[i][field]))
                      out.push(input[i]);
              }
            return out;
          };
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="tesapp" ng-controller="tesCtrl">
    <h1>Mencoba Filtering</h1>
    <h2>Mencoba ng-click</h2>
    <div class="col col-4">
      <label class="select">
        <select name="gender" ng-model="alfabet">
          <option value="^" selected disabled>Alphabet</option>
          <option value="^(A|a)">A</option>
          <option value="^(B|b)">B</option>
          <option value="^(C|c)">C</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
    <ul ng-repeat="name in namaIt =  track by $index">
      <li>{{name}}</li>
    </ul>
    <div ng-switch="alfabet">
      <div ng-switch-default>
        <ul ng-repeat="tes in item.stores | regex:'name':alfabet | orderBy: 'preparation' | orderBy: 'name'">
          <input type="button" ng-click="klikIseng(tes)" value="klik gue">
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == ''" >{{tes.name}} kosong</li>
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == '1'">{{tes.name}} satu</li>
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == '2'">{{tes.name}} dua</li>
          <li ng-if="tes.preparation == '3'">{{tes.name}} tiga</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="1">
        <ul ng-repeat="tes in item.stores | orderBy: 'preparation'">
          <li>{{tes.name}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to make a list of what I have clicked, if I use normal Json, it works because I can get what I have clicked directly to the ng-click function...

Is there any solution to this?

Thank you so much

Comment: Why can't you use ng-click with a function and the data selected?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, actually I have put the ng-click inside the ng-repeat function, search the input tag inside the ng-switch, I hope you find it anyway... The way is, that if I put the normal .json, the it worked but if I put a website api, it doesn't work anymore, it feels like the AJAX don't work if you dont work with .json files.

Comment: is it possible to share data or give some runable sample data? @Yuko Pangestu